# Why this jquery code don't work?

Tags: jquery, html

I write this jquery code for replacing text , but this code don't work .
Here is post section code :

```
<div class="post-text" >
 <p>&nbsp;#s-product-name# دانلود نرم افزار #e-product-name#</p>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery code :

```
if ($(".post-text").html().indexOf("#s-product-name#") > 0) {
      $(".post-text").html($(".post-text").html().replace(/#s-product-name#/g , "<a id='s-product-name' >"));
      $(".post-text").html($(".post-text").html().replace(/#e-product-name#/g , "</a>"));
    }
```

The jquery codes are in the end of HTML page .
Can you help me , please ?

Comment: I write wrong question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=".post-text" >
```

Delete dot before className

```
<div class="post-text" > // it is correct
```

And

```
if ($(".post-text").html().indexOf("#s-product-name#") + 1)
```

instead

```
if ($(".post-text").html().indexOf("#s-product-name#") > 0)
```

This return `true`